# Does cuMemcpy "care" about the current context?

Tags: cuda, copy, multi-gpu, cuda-context, cuda-driver

Suppose I have a GPU and driver version supporting unified addressing; two GPUs, G0 and G1; a buffer allocated in G1 device memory; and that the current context C0 is a context for G0.

Under these circumstances, is it legitimate to [`cuMemcpy()`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-driver-api/group__CUDA__MEM.html#group__CUDA__MEM_1g8d0ff510f26d4b87bd3a51e731e7f698) from my buffer to host memory, despite it having been allocated in a different context for a different device?

So far, I've been working under the assumption that the answer is "yes". But I've recently experienced some behavior which seems to contradict this assumption.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `cuMemcpy` from another context is legal, regardless of which device the context was created on. Depending on which case you are in, I recommend the following:

- If this is a multi-threaded application, double-check your program and make sure you are not releasing your device memory before the copy is completed
- If you are using the `cuMallocAsync`/`cuFreeAsync` API to allocate and/or release memory, please make sure that operations are correctly stream-ordered
- Run [compute-sanitizer](https://docs.nvidia.com/compute-sanitizer/ComputeSanitizer/index.html) on your program

If you keep experiencing issues after these steps, you can file a bug with NVIDIA [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia_bug/add).

Comment: Surely this only applies on unified memory platforms?

Comment: UVA is expected/needed